# How to measure program.exe startup time?

Tags: c, windows, performance, winapi, performance-testing

I want to measure my program exe startup time it
is the time from the moment of click or [enter]
if started from console or any other way till 
the moment when program startup is done and 
its code can execute with all structures set up
(probably it means when first commands in main()
are executed [?])

I want to measure it programmaticaly from 
inside of my code - so i think a way to do it
would need to read an exact time of firing 
the program then substract this time from
the time of first line of codes execution

(sorry for my bad english) How to do it?

Comment: How about reading the performance counter before the program starts and in its `main()` and storing the two values in some file and then calculating the difference?

Comment: how to call qpc before my program starts (is loaded to ram) ?

Comment: Rewrite it in java - you can then use a stopwatch.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to measure from the click or [enter], which includes the shell (cmd.exe or Windows Explorer) overhead, or from program startup?

Programatically you can only measure time from process creation, so that won't include finding, reading and mapping the .exe file or any DLLs.  The timing will vary depending on what is already mapped in virtual memory.  It will include initialisation of the C RTL, but not much else.

Probably the best you can do is [GetProcessTimes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms683223%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The problem is that even the parent process does not necessarily wait for the child process initialisation to complete -- it could, using the `WaitForInputIdle`, but if you are using standard tools like Windows Explorer then you stuck with that.  I can't see any way to measure the shell overhead without writing your own.

Comment: And if I would write my own process starter ? then I could show the exact time of Run("Program.exe") then in main of program.exe show the exact time of main entering - will it be exact way of measuring my startup (This is ugly becouse I would like to get it from my setupped program not with use of external starter but if the good way is not avaliable I would like try this worse one at least)